# input tag loses focus after one character in react-querybuilder

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a customized [react-querybuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-querybuilder). Whenever I add a rule the input box is rendered with default empty value. The problem is that when I enter one character in the Input box it loses focus.

This does seem like a duplicate question. But, after trying out the solutions mentioned below -

1. Storing value in state.
2. autoFocus on input tag (this is messed it up even further!)

I am not able to figure it out. 
I have added the code to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6g5ygt?file=Filter.js)

Please find the relevant code:

```
  const [queryOutput, setQueryOutput] = useState("");
  ...
      <QueryBuilder
        {...props}
        controlElements={{
          combinatorSelector: props => {
            let customProps = {
              ...props,
              value: props.rules.find(x => x.combinator) ? "or" : props.value
            };
            return (
              <div className="combinator-wrapper">
                <button className="form-control-sm btn btn-light mt-2">
                  {customProps.value.toUpperCase()}
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          },
          addRuleAction: props => {
            return (
              <button
                className={props.className}
                title={props.title}
                onClick={e => {
                  return props.handleOnClick(e);
                }}
              >
                + Add New Rule
              </button>
            );
          },
          addGroupAction: props => {
            return (
              <button
                className={props.className}
                title={props.title}
                onClick={e => {
                  return props.handleOnClick(e);
                }}
              >
                {props.label}
              </button>
            );
          },
          valueEditor: ({
            className,
            field,
            operator,
            inputType,
            value,
            handleOnChange,
            level
          }) => {
            if (field === "enabled") {
              return (
                <input
                  className={className}
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={value !== "" ? value : false}
                  onChange={e => handleOnChange(e.target.checked)}
                />
              );
            }
            return (
              <input
                className={className}
                value={value}
                onChange={e => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
        onQueryChange={query => {
          let customQuery = { ...query, combinator: "or" };
          return setQueryOutput(
            formatQuery(customQuery ? customQuery : query, "sql")
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: This behavior typically happens when the input component is remounting each render. Its most likely a bad pattern in your code. Can you add the relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: @BrianThompson added the relevant code in question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to assign a reference of the `valueEditor` component rather than defining it inline(so that it does not create a new instance on every render). 
Updated the relevant code:

```
const valueEditor = ({
          className,
          field,
          operator,
          inputType,
          value,
          handleOnChange,
          level
        }) => (
          <input
            className={className}
            value={value}
            onChange={e => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
          />
        );
     .....
 <QueryBuilder
      {...props}
      controlElements={{
      ...
      valueEditor
      ...
      }}
  />
```